# Some data field not pushing to list

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
userSPMSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
  userSPMList.push(userSPM.fromFirestore(doc));
});
console.log(userSPMList)
```

I am not sure why when I push my data to a list, some of the fields lose their values. My console shows that fields like enrollmentYear have a value at first but the moment I push my data to list that value becomes null. However, some fields are still present like Id.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code from `fromFirestore` with us. Maybe there is something going wrong and you get a null returned.

Comment: @TarikHuber I added another picture to more of my code.

Comment: We need the code of `fromFirestore` it's probabyl in the userSPM class. Can you also pls share the code snippet driecty and not only pictures. If we need to make chages no one here will rewrite your code using the pictures. thx

Comment: @TarikHuber I checked my userSPM class realised I had left out some of the fields.  Thank you so much for pointing me there, I had not thought to check it. Code works as expected now. :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `fromFirestore` in your userSPm class as explained in the commends before.